# Bootstrap 3.0.3: dropdown menu-items not clickable on mobile

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, joomla, joomla3.0

On my [website](http://www.huystemoock.nl) the links in the dropdown menu's are not working on mobile devices (Android ánd iOS). That means that when I click on a menu item on desktop, it works fine, and when I click the same item on my iPod touch it just closes the dropdown and does nothing. The parent items function well.

For example: when I press 'Activiteiten' and then press 'Wandelroute', nothing happens on mobile. When I draw my window (on desktop) at a width of 320px (like the width of a mobile device) the menu just works. I doubt whether my code causes the problem or the mobile device does.

What I've tried so far:

- I've put jQuery and Bootstrap in the right order;
- Included bootstrap-dropdown.js;
- Included the following code:

  .dropdown-backdrop 
  { position: static; }

And then there's that other strange thing. On [this](http://www.huystemoock.nl/vrienden) page of the same website, the menu functions okay on mobile devices. I've got absolutely no idea what's different on that page compared to the other ones.

I'm using Joomla 3.x, jQuery 1.11.1 and Bootstrap 3.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be something to do with the error that is bring thrown in the browser console, which is coming from this code:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('touchstart.dropdown.data-api', (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation() )
```

You should find this in the **index.php** of your template folder. Once located, change to the following:

```
$('.dropdown-menu').on('touchstart.dropdown.data-api', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code. I took that code from over here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/4550#issuecomment-8684262 but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe because it's written for an earlier version of Bootstrap (2). Right now there are no errors in the console any more.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered my fault: I used a 'Joomla'-version of Bootstrap on my website. That version was optimized for Joomla by a Joomla-plugin-programmer. Now I use the legacy version of Bootstrap 3 and my menu works just fine again.